# Dividing numbers by 2 with some restriction

Tags: c, function

So I need to need to make a divide function which will take a number from the main class and divide it by 2.

This is what I have so far:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
  int num = 20;
  divide(num);
  printf(num);
}

void divide(int* a)
{
  int prod = a;
  int y;
  y = prod/2;
}
```

I think that the only part I'm having trouble at unless that code above is wrong.

Thanks!

Comment: **Please** compile with warnings enabled, and consider **every warning that the C compiler emits** to be **an error, made by you**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two mistakes here, that unfortunately C makes relatively easy to make.

First, you need to pass a pointer into divide, but you're currently passing an integer that's getting converted to a pointer. In other words, you need to pass the address of `num`, not the value `num`. In short, you need to use `divide(&num)` rather than `divide(num)`.

Second, you're making a similar mistake in `divide`. You've accepted a pointer to an integer, `a`, and then you're dividing `a` by 2. `a` isn't an integer. It's a *pointer to an integer*! If you want to operate on the value pointed to by `a`, you must dereference it. In other words, you need `a* = *a / 2;`.

---

As a side note, you should crank up the warnings of whatever compiler your using. All of the major compilers will warn you if you're converting an integer to a pointer or a pointer to an integer without an explicit cast. For example, if you're using gcc, you might want to use the `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` flags (or go read the gcc documentation and find some flags that fit you better). This could look like `gcc -o some_prog -Wall -Wextra -pedantic some_prog.cpp`.

Comment: `a* = *a / 2;` → `*a = *a / 2;`. And third mistake: The OP's `printf` is wrong.

Comment: thanks works and @CoolGuy fixed it printf("%i", num);

Answer (score 3):

I assume this is a homework question. For future reference, when it is a homework question, you should tag it as such.

This question is about pointers. The core concept here is that the divide function takes a pointer to an integer. A pointer is a location in memory - with that pointer, it can go directly to that location and modify the value there. Then main() will be able to see the value without needing to have it returned from divide().

The first step is to write divide. I will include comments to explain what each step does.

```
void divide(int* a)
{
  //go to the location in memory referenced by a and get the value
  int aValue = *a;

  //divide the value by 2
  aValue = aValue / 2;

  //store the value in the memory location referenced by a
  *a = aValue;
}
```

The next step is to change your main function a little bit. Right now you pass divide() and integer. You need to pass it an integer pointer.

Try the following. The "&" operator gets the memory address of a variable.

```
int main()
{
  int num = 20;
  divide(&num);
  printf("%d\n", num);
}
```

Note that this program may run into errors if it tries to divide an odd number by 2, but for your example this should do fine. Let me know of any other questions.

Comment: "_when it is a homework question, you should tag it as such._" -- Nope. Also, there isn't a tag [tag:homework]

Comment: @CoolGuy So maybe the word 'tag' is wrong here, but the general policy is that you should be clear that it is homework right?

Comment: "_the general policy is that you should be clear that it is homework right?_" Hmm. I haven't thought of that. So, I don't know...